# JTree Organization

Tags: java, jtree

I have a JTree that I would like to populate with "Task" objects. Each "Task" has a Date field. When I add Task to JTree, I would like it to be sorted into the appropriate Date Category like as follows:

```
-Today
-Yesterday
-Last Week
    -Monday
-This Year
    -Jan
       -Date
          -Task

    -...
-Previous Years 
    -2015
       -Jan
         -Date
            -Task
```

I would like to be able add Tasks after the JTree is displayed and have the Tree built based on the dates of the Task. What would be the cleanest easiest way to do this?

Comment: Use the underlying `TreeModel` or provide a custom one.

Comment: Yes, I have gotten that far, but i'm trying to figure out a way to populate the "Parent Nodes (Today, Yesterday etc)" as they are needed . For example, if i put in one Task only and its date was yesterday, I only need one parent Node- "Yesterday", with that Task as its child.

Comment: And what's the problem? You could only keep those nodes in the model or keep them all but hide those that don't contain any tasks, i.e. play with the `getChild()` and `getChildCount()` methods.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, can't provide an example. I'd probably internally keep the nodes in some tree structure and maintain a "filtered" copy of that structure that only contains nodes which in turn contain tasks (directly or down the hierarchy). Read up on the methods I suggested and try something. You'll learn more that way,